# Seaplane from Bali to Rinca?

Tags: air-travel, budget, indonesia, bali

I'm trying to understand if it's possible (even economically) to directly reach Rinca Island from Bali by seaplane. Anyone has information in regard of this?

I've found very few pages on the web, most of them a few years old now, and all talks about doing a V.I.P. service.

Comment: Thx Jonik for the Rinca tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search I've found a really simple answer: Rinca island is in a natural park area and it is a no flight zone.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would be to [try chartering a private seaplane](http://www.omnitrips.com/our-services/seaplane-transfers-charters/) in [Bali](http://www.omnitrips.com/our-services/seaplane-transfers-charters/omni-marine-seaplane-bali/) and see if they will take you.  There are no scheduled flights - you need to fly to [Labuan Bajo](http://www.gardenaflores.com/airports/lbj/) and take a boat from there if you're not interested in private rental.

Comment: thx, but they are just one of the various web site anyone can find easily (and I did) with a basic query on a search engine...and they talk about luxury.